# How to launch Spring Task using Spring CLoud stream with custom parameters

Tags: java, spring, stream, cloud, task

I am able to run the below mentioned Spring cloud stream which takes a message from rabbitmq, transforms to tasklaunch request and trigger a task using Task-laucher-local. This works perfectly fine.

> stream create task-stream-1 --definition "source: rabbit
>   --rabbit.queues=AspWorkflow --spring.rabbitmq.username=RabbitAdmin --spring.rabbitmq.password=admin --spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost --spring.rabbitmq.port=5672|tasklaunchrequest-transform --uri=maven://com.workflows.task:CloudTaskJavaExec:1.0-SNAPSHOT --command-line-arguments='--executablePath=D:\Documents\Official\Platform-X\Execs\SimpleJavaProgram-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
>   --spring.rabbitmq.username=RabbitAdmin --spring.rabbitmq.password=admin --spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost --spring.rabbitmq.port=5672|task-launcher-local --rabbit.queues=AspWorkflow --spring.rabbitmq.username=RabbitAdmin --spring.rabbitmq.password=admin --spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost --spring.rabbitmq.port=5672" stream deploy task-stream-1 --properties "app.source.rabbit.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.binder=rabbit,app.tasklaunchrequest-transform.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.binder=rabbit,app.tasklaunchrequest-transform.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.binder=rabbit,app.task-launch-local.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.binder=rabbit"

But instead of passing the Uri and Command line arguments directly in the deployment time, I want to take those from the incoming message and then launch a request.

I created a TaskLaunchRequest and fed to the input queues of the sink but still I am not able to achive the behaviour I need with runtime param passing.

My sample TaskLaunchRequest looks as below

```
{
  "uri": "maven://com.workflows.task:CloudTaskJavaExec:1.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "commandlineArguments": [
    "--executablePath=D:\\Documentsts\\Official\\Platform-X\\Execs\\SimpleJavaProgram-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
  ],
  "environmentProperties": {

  },
  "deploymentProperties": {

  }
}
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use TaskLaunchRequest-transform

***Another option to start a task using the task-launcher would be to create a stream using the Tasklaunchrequest-transform processor to translate a message payload to a TaskLaunchRequest.***

You should implement your own processor as similar to TasklaunchrequestTransformProcessorConfiguration and set the command line arguments for the tasklaunchrequest from the message instead of properties being passed.

Sample code (not complete code)

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
public Object setupRequest(Object message) {
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> deploymentProperties = null;
    List<String> commandLineArgs = null;
    ...
    ...
    commandLineArgs = **<parse your message and get the commandline args>**

    TaskLaunchRequest request = new TaskLaunchRequest(
            processorProperties.getUri(),
            commandLineArgs,
            properties,
            deploymentProperties,
            null);

    return request;
}
```

Please refer below github link for the original source code of the TasklaunchrequestTransformProcessorConfiguration.

https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklaunchrequest-transform/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-tasklaunchrequest-transform/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/tasklaunchrequest/transform/processor/TasklaunchrequestTransformProcessorConfiguration.java

Hope this helps.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: sure, sorry i thought providing github link for the source code of the processor would be sufficient. Anyways, you can implement your own processor as similar to https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklaunchrequest-transform/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-tasklaunchrequest-transform/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/tasklaunchrequest/transform/processor/TasklaunchrequestTransformProcessorConfiguration.java.